# React / JSX Dynamic Number of Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, meteor-react

In React, is it possible to render a variable number of HTML tags or React Components?

For example, in the code below, `this.renderStats()` can render 0 to 2 `<i>` tags depending on the variables `stats.health` and `stats.energy`.

The following code prints out `[object Object]`

```
class Hero extends React.Component {

    showBadges(stats) {
        let badgeList = []
        if (stats.health > 1000) {
            badgeList += <i className="fa fa-times-circle" style={{color: "red"}}></i>
        }
        if (stats.energy > 100) {
            badgeList += <i className="fa fa-times-circle" style={{color: "blue"}}></i>
        }
        return badgeList;
    }

    renderStats() {
        return this.props.users.map((stats) => {
            return (
                <Td className="align-middle" column="badges">{ this.showBadges(stats) }</Td>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <Table>
                { this.renderStats() } 
            </Table>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Short answer: yes, because I do it often. Why is it returning `object Object`, probably doing something wrong. Can you try rendering your `renderStats` without `this.showBadges(stats)`, just have something like `placeholder` there and see what outputs. If that outputs it correctly, then it's probably the way you're generating the array in `showBadges`

Comment: @A.Lau If I use some text `123` as the placeholder, I see `123` rendered in it's place

Comment: Instead of `+=` have you tried `badgeList.push(<i>...</i>)`? You're using `+=` on an object, instead of `push`, which will give you `[object Object]`. You can see this on normal javascript if you were to do that with `+= {}`. I'm guessing you were looking to stringify it instead? `"<i>...</i>"`

Comment: @A.Lau Using `.push` and enclosing `badgeList` with `<div>` elements solved it:   `return (
   <div>
    { badgeList }
   </div>
  );`

Comment: is the enclosing `<div>` necessary? doesn't feel like it should since it's returning an array.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `showBadges` function to:

```
showBadges(stats) {
    let badgeList = []
    if (stats.health > 1000) {
       badgeList.push(<i className="fa fa-times-circle" style={{color: "blue"}}></i>)
    }
    if (stats.energy > 100) {
       badgeList.push(<i className="fa fa-times-circle" style={{color: "blue"}}></i>)
    }
    return badgeList;
}
```

And it should work.

Comment: if you want to use array keep in mind that you should provide `key` prop

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a list of children dynamically as @Boky pointed out or take a full advantage of JSX and use inline expressions:

```
showBadges(stats) {
  return (
    <span>
      {
        stats.health > 1000 &&
        <i className="fa fa-times-circle" style={{color: "blue"}}></i>
      }
      {
        stats.energy > 100 &&
        <i className="fa fa-times-circle" style={{color: "blue"}}></i>
      }
    </span>
  )
}
```

You can use either simple **boolean expression** (`condition && <Component />`) or **ternary operator** (`condition ? <ComponentIfTrue /> : <ComponentIfFalse />`)